# When using lmer is a random intercept being estimated more than once if specified in seperate grouping factors?

Tags: r, mixed-model, model-selection, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I know there are a slew of lmer specification questions already floating around.  Please let me know if this is a duplicate, or if it is deemed off-topic, and I'll delete it.

I am using a forward stepwise approach in an attempt to optimially specify the random effects structure for my data.  The base model I am attempting to step-up from has a random effects correlation structure like this:

```
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance
 38476 38632 -19220    38440
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr          
 SubjID (Intercept)  2.7844  1.6687                 
        SOA.s.c     39.1269  6.2551    0.931        
        SOA.s.c2    15.7080  3.9633   -0.943 -0.997 
Number of obs: 44061, groups: SubjID, 38
```

**Sub issue**:  I am (uneasily) at peace with the high correlations between the intercept, SOA.s.c, and SOA.s.c2.  Those values make some sense, although they are **much** higher than I would like.  I think I am correct in allowing them to be estimated so long as model still converges... but I stand ready to be corrected (and chided).

My step-up canidate models are the following:

1. `(1+SOA.s.c+SOA.s.c2|SubjID)+(1+SessionNum.c|SubjID)`
2. `(1+SOA.s.c+SOA.s.c2|SubjID)+(0+SessionNum.c|SubjID)`
3. `(1+SOA.s.c+SessionNum.c+SOA.s.c2|SubjID)`

**Actual Question**:  Given that repeated measures were taken for each SubjID along each of the three above listed variables, are each of these three sensible options to test?  In particular, I am concerned with model 1, because it provides the lowest AIC and BIC, but appears to estimate yet another SubjID interept.  Is that really what it is doing?  Is that okay?

**For reference**:

The random effects correlations for the first set, `(1+SOA.s.c+SOA.s.c2|SubjID)+(1+SessionNum.c|SubjID)`, look like this:

```
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance
 38284 38466 -19121    38242
Random effects:
 Groups Name         Variance  Std.Dev. Corr          
 SubjID (Intercept)   2.687227 1.63928                
        SOA.s.c      39.713777 6.30189   0.968        
        SOA.s.c2     16.853598 4.10531  -0.984 -0.995 
 SubjID (Intercept)   0.224172 0.47347                
        SessionNum.c  0.070583 0.26567  0.977         
Number of obs: 44061, groups: SubjID, 38
```

The random effects correlations for the second set, `(1+SOA.s.c+SOA.s.c2|SubjID)+(0+SessionNum.c|SubjID)`, look like this:

```
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance
 38307 38472 -19134    38269
Random effects:
 Groups Name         Variance  Std.Dev. Corr          
 SubjID (Intercept)   2.939991 1.71464                
        SOA.s.c      40.131292 6.33493   0.932        
        SOA.s.c2     15.941733 3.99271  -0.941 -0.996 
 SubjID SessionNum.c  0.066763 0.25839
```

The random effects correlations for the second set, `(1+SOA.s.c+SOA.s.c2+SessionNUm.c|SubjID)`, look like this:

```
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance
 38286 38477 -19121    38242
Random effects:
 Groups Name         Variance Std.Dev. Corr                 
 SubjID (Intercept)   2.98820 1.72864                       
        SOA.s.c      39.85077 6.31275   0.932               
        SessionNum.c  0.07066 0.26582   0.316  0.050        
        SOA.s.c2     16.94324 4.11622  -0.947 -0.995 -0.052
```

Comment: Those SOAs... they must be just transforms of each other with a little noise.  They really look like they're measuring the same thing.  What are they?  Are they centred?

Comment: @John:  SOA.s.c is mean centered.  SOA.s.c2 is a quadratic transformation of SOA.s.c.  This forces all values of SOA.s.c2 to be positive - and so it is not 'mean' centered according to its own mean.  I was under the impression that it should not be mean centered and this this approach was more conceptually tractable.

Comment: I'd gladly drop SOA.s.c2 from the model, A) except model selection criteria (AIC & BIC) suggest it explains statistically significant amounts of variance both in random and fixed effects and B) The plotted predictions are much more 'sane' with SOA.s.c2 in the model.  Specifically, without SOA.s.c2 at low levels of SOA below chance levels of performance and predicted, but SOA.s.c2 causes those predictions to remain above chance.

Comment: Finally, although I am definitely interested in hearing about the issues associated with SOA.s.c2 they are not the driving factor in the model selection problem I am highlighting.  That is, models 1, 2, and 3 end up with similar structures even in the absence of SOA.s.c2 from the fixed and random effects structures.

Comment: I'm sure sure whether it is germane, but since you asked, SOA.s.c refers to the mean centered experimentally manipulated stimulus onset asynchrony (SOA), i.e. time between the stimulus to be judged and a visual mask obscuring that stimulus.  It is expected that at an SOA of 0 performance will fall to chance levels (in this case 50% / 0 in log-odds space).

Comment: To test polynomials you might want to look at `poly`.  Also, I'm guessing that log(SOA) will actually be a linear predictor and make the inclusion of the quadratic pointless. (it always does for me :) )

Comment: @John: Thanks I'll look at poly and the log transform and then update the question when I get the chance.  However, my primary question is still at issue. :)

Comment: @John: I'd also appreciate your input on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51155/how-would-you-report-in-publication-the-results-of-a-linear-model-fit-using-th/51165#51165

Comment: ... given the lack of response on the following, I am probably going to leave my data structured in the way it already is... and wait for the main question to be addressed.